# c++ Cout keeps repeating while inputting

Tags: c++, function, polymorphism, cout

I believe that my code is correct but after I input the cardholder name, the whole thing I am trying to input repeats constantly.

```
    Print Cards by selecting the type (0 when done): 
    1. Basic Card 
    2. ID Card 
    3. Bank Card 
    Card Type: 2
    Institution name: a
    Cardholder name: lola
    Expiration date mmddyyyy (0 if none): 

    Institution name: Cardholder name: Expiration date mmddyyyy (0 if none): 

    Institution name: Cardholder name: Expiration date mmddyyyy (0 if none): 

    Institution name: Cardholder name: Expiration date mmddyyyy (0 if none): 

    Institution name: Cardholder name: Expiration date mmddyyyy (0 if none): 

    Institution name: Cardholder name: Expiration date mmddyyyy (0 if none):
```

What do I have to do in order to avoid that? Is it with the argument I put in the for loop?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>

    int main ()
    {
        std::vector <Card*> cardbook;
int card_type;
std::string institute_name;
std::string card_name;
int expire_date;
int identify_num;
int birthdate;
int account_num;
int secure_code;

std::cout << "Print Cards by selecting the type (0 when done): " << std::endl
          << " 1. Basic Card " << std::endl
          << " 2. ID Card " << std::endl
          << " 3. Bank Card " << std::endl;

std::cout << "Card Type: " ;
std::cin >> card_type;

while (card_type)
{
    if (card_type == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "Institution name: ";
        getline (std::cin, institute_name);
        std::cin.ignore();
        std::cout << "Cardholder name: ";
        getline (std::cin, card_name);
        std::cin.ignore();
        std::cout << "Expiration date mmddyyyy (0 if none): ";
        std::cin >> expire_date;
        std::cout << std::endl <<std::endl;
        cardbook.push_back (new Card(institute_name, card_name, expire_date));
    }
    else if (card_type == 2)
    {
        std::cout << "Institution name: ";
        getline (std::cin, institute_name);
        std::cin.ignore();
        std::cout << "Cardholder name: ";
        getline (std::cin, card_name);
        std::cin.ignore();
        std::cout << "Expiration date mmddyyyy (0 if none): ";
        std::cin >> expire_date;
        std::cout << "ID number: ";
        std::cin >> identify_num;
        std::cout << "DOB mmddyyyy (0 if not listed)";
        std::cin >> birthdate;
        std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
        cardbook.push_back (new IDCard(institute_name, card_name, expire_date, identify_num, birthdate));
    }
    else if (card_type == 3)
    {
        std::cout << "Institution name: ";
        getline (std::cin, institute_name);
        std::cin.ignore();
        std::cout << "Cardholder name: ";
        getline (std::cin, card_name);
        std::cin.ignore();
        std::cout << "Expiration date mmddyyyy (0 if none): ";
        std::cin >> expire_date;
        std::cout << "Account number: ";
        std::cin >> account_num;
        std::cout << "Card Security Code: ";
        std::cin >> secure_code;
        std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
        cardbook.push_back (new BankCard (institute_name, card_name, expire_date, account_num, secure_code));
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}

for(auto& v : cardbook)
{
    v->print();
}
for (int i = 0; i < cardbook.size(); i++)
{
    delete cardbook[i];
}

return 0;
    }
```

Note: the string library is included in the header file. 
Also another question, if I want to input the cards in the order of expiration date, is the sort function the right function to use? Or would I use a for loop? Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you end the first input (the `2` for the card type) you ended it with a *newline*? That newline is also added to the input buffer, to be read by the very next call to `std::getline` and your input is no longer synchronized. Think about the *order* in which you do things, and remember that [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) reads and discard the newline.

Comment: I recommend you take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. If you used a debugger this problem should have been detected very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your input for the variable *card_type* only goes for one time and *while(card_type)* just goes forever since it's always none-zero. I guess what you are in need of is taking the input part into the loop.

---

Actually my suggestion is to use an IDE or some kind of debugger if you are a beginner of programming. Also it's a good habit to indent well and avoid duplicating code.

Answer (score 0):

Since your input for `card_type` is 2, and this value is never modified after that, your while loop will go on forever.

That's because any non-zero integer will evaluate to `true`. As an example, compiling and executing the following code :

```
int main(){
    int t = 134;
    while(t){
        cout << "t is true !" << endl;
    }
}
```

will keep printing `t is true !` until you stop the execution manually. This of course works with `if`, `while`... That means integers can be casted into booleans. Same can happen the other way around. `false` can be casted into an `int` and will take value 0, `true` will take value 1.

Long story short : Basically anything that expects a boolean value as a parameter can interpret integers as booleans, 0 being evaluated to `false` and all the other integers being evaluated to `true`.